# Vector Spaces and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a simple question. I'm not sure why I'm unable to clearly see what is going on here, but for some reason it's not apparent to me.

let W be the set of all vectors of the form shown, where a, b, and c represent arbitrary real numbers. In each case, either find a set S of vectors that spans W or give an example to show that W is not a vector space.

This matrix here is not a vector space, but I'm a bit confused why that's the case. How many of the properties do the below matrices not satisfy to be a vector space? What procedures need to be used?

What is a simple way to test if the zero matrix is present?

$$1) \begin{bmatrix} 3a + b \\ 4 \\ a - 5b \end{bmatrix}$$

$$2)\begin{bmatrix} -a + 1 \\ a-6b \\ 2b+a \end{bmatrix} $$

How can I develop the vision to be able to see if a vector space exists from just looking at a matrix?

Comment: Find $a,b$ such that the given vector is $\vec 0$.

Comment: so for #1 you cannot setup the equation to solve for 0 because of the constant 4?

Comment: Exactly.  $\quad$

Comment: Not really. The symbols I find a bit confusing and the fact that it's not written as a matrix. I'm sorry I'm very daft when it comes to linear algebra.

Comment: W.r.t. your last question: practice, practice, practice.  For each example, go through your axioms one-by-one.  Eventually you'll start noticing which ones are easier to prove and which ones not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a vector space - or a subspace in this case - we need two things:

1. $0 \in W$
2. For all vectors $v,w \in W$ and all scalars $\lambda \in F$ (where $F$ is the field over which we are working - for example $F = \mathbb R$) we have that $\lambda v, v+w \in W$

In the first case the zero-vector is not representable - no matter what $a,b$ we choose. Therefore this is not a subspace/vector space.

In the second case we also can not find $a,b$ such that we obtain the zero-vector. Hence this is also not a vector space

If you have a vector of this form with $a,b$ being arbitrary real numbers you know that the described set is a vector space if it can be written in the form
$a v+bw$ where $v,w$ are vectors not depending on $a$ and $b$ anymore.

For example the set of all vectors $\begin{pmatrix} a+2b\\-3a+b\\2a+2b \end{pmatrix}$ is a vector space as it can be written in the form
$$a \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\-3\\2\end{pmatrix}+b \begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$
From this representation we immediately see that by setting $a=b=0$ the first condition is fulfilled.
The second condition is also true in this case. Say we have the set of all vectors $av+bw$ with $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Then the sum of two such vectors $a_1v+b_1w$ and $a_2v+b_2w$ is $(a_1+a_2)v + (b_1 +b_2)w$ which is again an element of the given set. For a $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ we get $\lambda \cdot (av+bw) = (\lambda a) v + (\lambda b)w$ which is also an element of the set. Hence such a set of vectors is a vector space.