# Vector spaces & Subspaces -

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Another simple question. Linear algebra has been hard on me for some reason.

I have a follow up question to another question that I [previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398766/vector-spaces-and-subspaces) about vector spaces and subspaces.

Given

The set $B = \{1-t^2, t - t^2, 2 - t +t^2\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{P_2}$.

Is this a subspace? Couldn't this be written as below?

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1-t^2\\
 t - t^2\\
 2 - t +t^2\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

This is not a subspace.

$$\begin{bmatrix} -a + 1 \\ a-6b \\ 2b+a \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: $1-t^2$ is a vector, not the component of a vector. Don't let the notation trip you up, when they are polynomials you write them as $ax^0 + bx^1 + cx^2$ instead of $ax_0 + bx_1 + cx_2$. Both of these are the vector $[a,b,c]^T$ with different notation.

Comment: Hm! That might be what's hanging me up.....